# I want to pass in a file in C line by line and read using scanf but skip the first line

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int 
main(void){

 //Declare variables
  //Want to read the first line and then ignore it.  From the second line
  //I scan in the input values and then store them in their individual arrays.

     int yy, mm, dd, loc;
     double mx, mm;
         /*Read and discard the first line of the file*/
          scanf("%*[^\n]");

         /*Read from the second line*/
         while(scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%lf,%lf\n",
                    &loc, &yy, &mm, &dd, &mx, &mn) == 6){

            //Storing each input in its own array.
  }

}
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Well when I pass the file in it fails to read any line at all, I assumed that it is because it does not skip the first line which is comprised of titles (chars) and thus breaks the while loop.

Comment: The code shown is not opening any files. Moreover `scanf` reads only form `stdin`...

Comment: @LPs According to [the `stdin` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html), what is the type of `stdin`?

Comment: @Seb While you are semantically correct, I bet Op is not redirecting `stdin` to the file he want to read ;)

Comment: [mcve], please!

Comment: "Your program should read the entire input dataset into a collection of parallel arrays."
That is the directions we were given, along with a hint: "You should use a seperate while(getchar()) loop to consume the first line"

I am not very good with this sorry guys so I do appreciate the help.

Comment: *sigh*... so you've given us some faulty code and a vague, irrelevant question, and left out a crucial part of the question (your entire assignment specification).

Why not just give us the assignment specsheet together with your code and ask us what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%*[^\n]");` will indeed read and discard up to the first newline, but won't discard the newline itself. I suggest pairing that with `getchar();`.

`\n` within a format string doesn't do what you think it does; as `scanf` isn't line-oriented (but instead field-oriented), you may find it'll discard *all whitespace characters*, not just *newlines*. I wouldn't see that as a problem. If you want to literally discard the remainder of the line, you could do so using the same code suggested to discard the first line:

```
scanf("%*[^\n]");
getchar();
```

---

There are two declarations of `mm` in your code, though you've not mentioned an error message so *I guess* your testcase isn't accurate and you intended one of them (the `double`) to be `mn` instead.

With those issues covered, as [my testcase](http://ideone.com/JHQTGG) (included below) demonstrates I'd expect that your program is capable of reading and discarding the first line, and then reading four fields of `int`s as decimal digits followed by two fields of `double`s as decimal digits, separated by commas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int yy, mm, dd, loc;
    double mx, mn;

    scanf("%*[^\n]");
    getchar();

    while (scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%lf,%lf\n", &loc, &yy, &mm, &dd, &mx, &mn) == 6){
        printf("<%d> <%d> <%d> <%d> <%f> <%f>\n", loc, yy, mm, dd, mx, mn);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: By the looks of one of your comments, this doesn't actually meet your assignment requirements. *"You should use a seperate while(getchar()) loop to consume the first line"*, and so `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();` should be replaced with your loop.

If you end up adding an attempt at that loop to your question, feel free to ping me so I can provide feedback.